# Tkinter gui and website linkage is possible?

Tags: javascript, python, tkinter, web, chatbot

I have created a tkinter gui (chatbot) using python and another website using html css and javascript. I want to show that gui in my website as chatbot. Can you help me with that?

The website and that tkinter gui are working properly. Help me with showing that gui in website.

Comment: Have a look on Django.